# List of commonly supported Camera picture sizes

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, resolution

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486143/supported-camera-preview-sizes-for-popular-android-handsets), 640x480 **preview** size/resolution can reasonably be expected to be supported on most devices. What about the picture (rather than preview) resolution/size?  Is there a way to find out or an existing resource listing commonly supported **picture** resolutions/sizes across the devices out there?  My impression is that 640x480 picture size is widely supported, but what else?

I realize that [getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29) returns a list picture sizes the current device supports, but I'd like to have an idea of what the distribution of supported picture sizes out there is, across the range of devices out there in the world.  From what I could see, neither the [Dashboads](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) nor the [Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) provide this information.

Note 1: One possible way of approximating the data is to start with a list of popular Android devices such as [this one](http://www.androidpit.com/10-most-popular-android-devices-in-the-u-s), and find out supported camera picture sizes on those phones. Most of the specs sites (such as [this one](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_google_nexus_s-3620.php) or [this one](http://www.handsetdetection.com/properties/vendormodel/Samsung/GT-I9000)) only have maximum resolution listed.

Note 2: [it appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943940/2149548) that on some phones [setPictureSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28%29) is, for all intents and purposes, broken, and therefore should not be used; however it would still be useful to know common picture sizes for other (non-broken) Android devices.

Comment: Why not just let the camera take the photo at the default resolution, then scale it to your preferred size in an AsyncTask?

Comment: @Krylez I agree that it seems like you have to do that on Samsung Galaxy SIII; however, it seems like a bit of a roundabout way of doing things and slower as well. If most phones support, say, `1080x960`, and this is a sufficient resolution for my app, try waste resources taking a bigger picture?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So far the only way I could think of getting around this problem is to collect the information myself. You can find the results, and how to contribute [here](http://www.kirill.org/ar/ar.php)

Comment: great idea, I just installed the app on 3 devices and sent the camera data...hopefully more people will do it. So far it looks like 640x480 is the most popular resolution for both preview and pics